# How to create Box.com user from Salesforce Community User record?

Tags: apex, trigger, community, integration, community-cloud

I am looking for a way to create a user within Box.com if the user does not exist in Box.com after a Salesforce Community User record is created.

How can I create a user in box.com if one does not exists?

What I have tried, but couldn't find out how to get it to work. It seems to not create any errors and errors don't show up in the logs.

```
trigger UserCreate on User(after create) {
  BoxApiConnection boxApi = new BoxApiConnection('accessToken');
  box.Toolkit boxToolkit = new box.Toolkit();
  for(User usr : Trigger.new) {
    String name = usr.FirstName;
    if(!BoxUser.getUser(name)) {
      BoxUser.createAppUser(boxApi, 'First_Last');
      boxToolkit.commitChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked with Box.com support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boxToolkit.commitChanges() could be an asynchronous callout, so any returned errors are likely several seconds later and included in a different log.